# jquery parse error when jquery in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an odd error parsing json data. The string `jQuery321040763556724467964_1507276501913??` was in the json response to a standard ajax request, at which point jquery chokes with

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  
at DOMEval (jquery.js:82)  
at Function.globalEval (jquery.js:346)  
at text script (jquery.js:9606)  
at ajaxConvert (jquery.js:8754)  
at done (jquery.js:9222)  
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9514)
```

And runs the ajax error callback. But the json is valid, and if the final two question marks are removed completes happily.

It also completes (with the ??) if instead of setting `dataType: 'json'` 
I supply no dataType and manually parse the response and pass that to the callback

```
this.send_ajax = function(payload, cb_success, cb_failed) {
    let r = {
        url: '/ajax',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        //dataType: 'json',   // see nb5137
        success: function(response) {
             cb_success(JSON.parse(response));
        },
        error: cb_failed
    }
    $.ajax(r);
}
```

What on earth is happening?

In response to remarks **this is not cross domain**.

Comment: The additional string is because you appear to be receiving JSONP, not JSON. Change to `dataType: 'jsonp` and remove the `JSON.parse` call as jQuery will already be doing that for you.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand you, but the weird string validly comes from the server. It is not jsonp.

Comment: Are you making a cross-domain request here? It would help a lot if you showed the complete jQuery AJAX request. It's hard to diagnose a problem with code you can't see.